# XCode's Build and Analyze - mistake or correct in finding Potential Leaks?

Tags: xcode, memory-leaks, code-analysis

How reliable is Xcode's "Build and Analyze" ?

I keep looking for the "potential leak" that it finds - but don't understand it.

Here the code:

```
-(void)viewDidLoad{

    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem;

    UIBarButtonItem *aBI = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemAdd
                                                                        target:self action:@selector(add:)];

    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = aBI;
    aBI.release;

    UIBarButtonItem *eB = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemOrganize
                                                                        target:self action:@selector(EinstellungenTapped:)];
    UIBarButtonItem * space = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace target:nil action:nil];


    UIBarButtonItem *emailB = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemCompose
                                                                       target:self action:@selector(emailTapped:)];


    NSArray* toolbarItems = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: eB,space,emailB,
                             nil];

    [self setToolbarItems: toolbarItems];

    eB.release;      // <------- Potential leak ??????
    emailB.release;  // <------- Potential leak ??????
    space.release;  // <------- Potential leak ??????
    }
```

Why should these three be potential leaks?

Even without the assignemt to the NSARRAY it's telling me about leaks.

What is wrong here?

many thanks....

Comment: To make it "worse"... here is a workaround, so that the warning does not come up anymore - however - I think it's still leaking:

just add assignments: self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = eB;

=> no warnings anymore.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I imagine the problem is because you're horribly mis-using dot syntax and confusing the static analyzer. You should never *ever* type `anObject.release`, because that has the completely wrong meaning. Dot syntax is designed for accessing properties, and has that specific semantic meaning, e.g. accessing a property. Anything which modifies the object itself should be a method, not a property, and should be called as such.

In other words, change those to

```
[eB release];
[emailB release];
[space release];
```

and things should work fine. Now the static analyzer should recognize that you really are releasing the objects.

As one final note, the fact that `eB.release` technically works can be considered an artifact of how the compiler works. While I don't believe that will ever break, I also don't know if it's guaranteed not to, and it's very bad form to rely upon.

Comment: Yes, I can't believe it - I totally overlooked those - of course, you are absolutely right.

Thanks very much for the extra pair of eyes!